# can a systemd service depends on a remote systemd service on linux?

Tags: linux, service, systemd, systemctl

I have two services that have dependency( service A in one host need to start before service B in another host).can anybody help me pls thanx so much.

Comment: No, what you describe isn't considered a case of a "dependency" by the definition/scope that applies to systemd services. What sort of software are you talking about ? is *service B* just a script that relies like on a database server *A*  or some such ? To be clear, Systemd has many different mechanisms of achieving the result you want, but the unit dependency system just isn't ment for that. Which exact mechanism(s) you could use, depend entirely on what sort of software we're talking about, are they scripts/daemons/..

Comment: I added an answer with other options. But there is no a simple answer for other options. It would be a very long article to explain the 3 other options. For example I am using control-m for a similar situation and the steps for it all product exclusive and only its steps would take 10-12 paragraphs with a lot of visuals. 
So you should search the keywords for further.
Good Luck!

Comment: thanx so much @Raxi

Comment: thanx so much @ust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Host1** = Includes the **ServiceA** which will start first

**Host2** = Includes the **ServiceB** which will start after ServiceA in Host1

You can build something like below in **simple** way:

1. In Host1; Start the ServiceA
2. Edit the **ServiceA**'s trigger (add one if it doesn't have or edit service program if it is possible) to **scp**, **rsync** or **ftp** a **control file** to Host2.
3. In Host2; add a script to check if the file arrived the location and start ServiceB if the file arrived. (You can use an input inside it to doublecheck if it comes from the Host1)
4. Add a cronjob fits the time for the script above.

**Edit:**
Other options:

1. If you have a **workflow management/orchestration** server you can use it.
2. With **webhooks**.
3. **Automation solutions** like **Jenkins**